# ListView on click listener

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I have designed a `ListFragment`. On `itemLongClick()`, an activity starts. `onActivityResult()`,I set the adapter again and a new text view is being created dynamically. `onClick` of each views in an item, a `Toast` shoud appear. If I implement `onClick()` on each views in adapter then `itemLongClick()` is not working.

I have attached my code below:

**inside `ListFragment`:**

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                clickPosition = position;
                Intent intent = new Intent(parent.getContext(),AddEventActivity.class );
                startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_EVENT);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

**inside adapter `getView()`:**

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_listview_items, null);
        TextView hour = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.hour);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layout);


        hour.setText(hourAL.get(position));
        if(eventAL.size() != 0){
            for(int i=0;i<eventAL.size();i++){
                if(eventAL.get(i).getPosition() == position){
                    for(int j =0;j<eventAL.get(i).eventName.size();j++){
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,1.0f);
                        params.setMargins(3, 3, 3, 3);
                        final TextView txt = new TextView(parent.getContext());
                        txt.setId(++textid);
                        txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                        txt.setLayoutParams(params);
                        txt.setText(eventAL.get(i).eventName.get(j));
                        layout.addView(txt);

                        txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), txt.getId() + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return view;
    }
```

Please someone guide me how to implement both functions.

Comment: Megha, You can write your LongClick inside getView() method. on Clicking on convertView you can do task whatever you want.

Comment: Either you have given on lick to your item child or whole item click,both are not work in your case.

Comment: try `txt.getId().toString` in Toast...

Comment: @pratt I cannot do that as there are other ListViews using the same adapter.

Comment: @MSGadag this doesn't make any change

Comment: r u getting error o just a idol screen?

Comment: there is no error. If I implement both functions then only onClick() works. In case of onLongClick() also, onClick() comes into action.

Comment: inside adapter for ListFragment, how can I implement startActivityForResult, so that i get the result in ListFragment and not in Activity?

Comment: debug and check wats happening....

Comment: n check even its same for onTouch event..

Comment: @MSGadag for the 1st time in any row long_click works. But once a view is added to that row, only on_click is in action, onLongClick() doesn't work on a row after addition of a view to that particular row.

Comment: @pratt even if I implement both the functions inside adapter, issue exists.

Comment: i want to implement feature same as android calender. In android calender; if any row is longClicked,you will be able to add new event, and if a row with event is clicked then event can be edited. I am able to edit the event but unable to add new event to same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out the solution. 
For my dynamic views, I have made setLongClickable() as true.